# Python- How to split text into paragraphs?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I would like to split text into paragraphs when I scrape it.
My codes below extract texts without dividing paragraphs.
Is there anyone who knows how to do that?

Here's my codes.

```
#extract articles from url
import urllib.request, urllib.error
import requests as req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

num=0
atc={}
for i in range(len(url)):
    res = req.get(url[i]).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res, "html.parser")
    elems = soup.find(class_='meteredContent css-1r7ky0e').get_text()
    str=""
    str+=elems
    atc[i]=str

#Dataframeにしてcsv
import csv
import pandas as pd

st=pd.DataFrame(atc,index=['text',])


st.T.to_csv("articles.csv",encoding='utf_8_sig')
```

Here's the text data I got from my codes.
[image]

There should be paragraphs.
[image]

Comment: I am not too sure but I think the link below might help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12616912/split-an-element-with-beautifulsoup

Comment: Can you share sample URL from where you get the text?

Comment: https://www.nytimes.com/2017/10/31/nyregion/police-shooting-lower-manhattan.html